# Inject @Qualifier in runtime

Tags: java, spring, cdi

I can't inject list of qualifier in runtime.
I created the interface and implemented it.

```
public interface AndamentoService {
    void realizar();
}
```

And implemented:

```
@Service
@FaseAndamento(FaseAndamento.Fase.ANALISE)
public class AndamentoAnaliseServiceImpl implements AndamentoService {
    @Override
    public void realizar() {

    }
}
@FaseAndamento(FaseAndamento.Fase.MARCACAO)
@Service
public class AndamentoMarcacaoServiceImpl implements AndamentoService {
    @Override
    public void realizar() {

    }
}
```

I created the qualifier annotation to be able to inject my classes:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR})
@Qualifier
public @interface FaseAndamento {

    Fase value();

    public static enum Fase {
        ANALISE,
        MARCACAO;
    }
}
```

This is the class to be able to retrieve the implementation at runtime, as if it were a factory

```
public class AndamentoAnnotationLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<FaseAndamento> implements FaseAndamento{
    private Fase value;
    private AndamentoAnnotationLiteral(Fase value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public Fase value() {
        return value;
    }
    public static AndamentoAnnotationLiteral andamento(Fase value){
        return new AndamentoAnnotationLiteral(value);
    }
}
```

When I inject my list of Andamento, like this:

```
@ViewScoped
@Named
@Controller
public class RealizarAndamentoController implements Serializable{

    @Inject @Any
    private Instance<AndamentoService> andamentos;

    @Inject
    @FaseAndamento(FaseAndamento.Fase.MARCACAO)
    private AndamentoService andamento;

    @PostConstruct
    public void realizarAndamento(){
        AndamentoService andamento = andamentos.select(AndamentoAnnotationLiteral.andamento(FaseAndamento.Fase.ANALISE)).get();
        andamento.realizar();
    }
}
```

**I get the following error:**
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type javax.enterprise.inject.Instance service.AndamentoService

Comment: It gives error in the I line:private Instance<AndamentoService> andamentos;

Comment: This error suggests that the service cannot be found. Is it part of the package scan?

Comment: You're using Spring, not CDI. Just inject a List<AndamentoService>.

Comment: ok, but in the line  private AndamentoService andamento he is inject right. Ide warns @Any("Cannot find bean qualified with @Any")

Comment: with @Autowired the same error

Comment: Spring supports Inject. But that doesn't mean it supports all of CDI. AFAIK, it doesn't support Any, and it doesn't support injecting Instance. Just remove Any, and inject a List<AndamentoService>.

Comment: But I need implementation AndamentoAnnotationLiteral. I need use Instance for it, I can't use List.

Comment: From CDI standpoint - not sure what's your bean discovery mode, but do try annotating your implementations with some [bean defining annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations) (for instance a scope). That should make sure it is found by CDI.